# Linux containers

Tags: docker, lxc, container

Linux containers

1- are containers really safe ? (I know that there was some vulnerabilities around like the one found in runc ... but are they really safe in general, since they use syscalls and an eventual kernel exploit may lead to a container escape)

2- what is the most reliable software to use for containerisation? (Lxc, docker, nspawn ... and how secure/stable/configurable are they)

3- is using containers to isolate the hosted services a good idea in general (containers vs non-containers)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct about some vulnerabilities. However they don't make it un-safe.
   The vulnerabilities can't make it less safe than no containers. The only way to make it safer, is to use hardware isolation (separate hardware for each service).
   Therefore keep your software up to date (latest security fixes).
2. Opinion alert: I use docker, there are others.
3. Containers don't isolate the host, they isolate the contained. Yes it will protect the host from the contained guests, and guests from each other.